# Git Submodules: how to know the commit/tag of the submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

due to company policies, we have very little tools in the toolbelt. I'm stuck with using Git for a number of things where *another tool* would do the work better, faster.

I need a specific dll in my project and the fastest way to get it was found to add a second repository as a submodule. I'm in the testing department, so I don't need the latest dll, nor the stable branch of the dll. I need a specific version of said dll, and I need fine control over it.

Luckily, I can use tags to navigate to the specific version. By `git checkout <tag>` I send the submodule in detached head and I can freeze the information with a commit of the superproject. Running `git status` doesn't explicitly tell me where I am with the submodule.

How can I explicitly get the information regarding tag the submodule is aligned within the detached head from the superproject? Ideally, I would like to have this information stored in plain text, for instance in the `.gitsubmodules` file. I want to be positive that the submodule is aligned with a given tag (or commit if the tag is not available) and I want to have this testable automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's note a few basic facts:

1. A submodule *is* a Git repository (so it has its own branch names, tag names, and commit objects).
2. A superproject is a Git repository in which the superproject Git goes into a submodule Git and does a `git checkout hash` (or `git switch --detach hash`), by hash ID, to get a detached HEAD in the submodule Git repository.  The hash ID used for this operation is the one recorded in a commit in the superproject.  (That's the hash ID you froze by committing.)

In other words, Git really *doesn't* use a tag to achieve this, even though *you did use one* to get the state that you then froze into a commit.  So...

> How can I explicitly get the information regarding tag the submodule is aligned within the detached head from the superproject?

... there are two different ways to deal with this:

- One way is to record, in the superproject—in something that Git itself *won't* use, because Git is going to use the hash ID in the commit—the tag name.
- The other way is to use the hash ID anyway, and then enter the submodule and see if there are some tag(s) that correspond to that hash ID.

These are the two overall strategies.  They have different consequences if someone chooses to do something that's technically-possible but recommended-against.  In particular, suppose someone who controls the submodule repository *alters the tags* in some way.  A tag like `v2.1` used to name commit `a123456` bu now names commit `b789abc`.  Perhaps `a123456` now has a tag `2.1alpha` instead.  Then:

- Asking the submodule *what tag(s) do you have for `a123456`* comes up with a new and different answer (`2.1alpha`), but you—or rather, your superproject Git, when you do `git submodule update`—will still check out and thus use `a123456` (the hash ID you froze earlier by committing).
- Asking the submodule *what hash ID do you have for `v2.1`* comes up with a new and different answer, `b789abc`.

If nobody does this frowned-upon thing, the question won't ever arise in the first place.  But you'll have to decide for yourself how it should be handled, if you think it might happen.

Now, as for recording items in `.gitmodules`, there *is* a way to do this.  The problem is that what Git will record is not a *tag* name but rather a *branch* name:

```
git submodule set-branch -b <name> submodule
```

will add:

```
branch = <name>
```

to the entry in the `.gitmodules` file.  The *`name`* you use here need not actually exist!  For instance, I just did:

```
git submodule set-branch -b v1.0 scripts
```

in a temporary test repo to which I added a submodule.  There is no `v1.0`, neither as branch nor tag, anywhere in the actual submodule.  Git completely ignores this name *unless* you run particular varieties of `git submodule update`.  I won't go into all of them, but for instance, consider this:

```
$ git submodule update --remote
fatal: Needed a single revision
Unable to find current origin/v1.0 revision in submodule path 'scripts'
```

Note that Git *assumed* `v1.0` was a *branch* name here, and added `origin/` in front of it; there is no way to tell it not to make this assumption.

The `.gitmodules` file is simply a Git configuration file, though, and can therefore be manipulated directly by `git config`.  You can read or write the `branch` entry, or invent your own entries.  There is a bit of danger to inventing your own: some future version of Git might invent the same thing, but use it in some different way.  Still, let's see what this does:

```
$ git config -f .gitmodules submodule.scripts.tag v1.0
$ git diff
diff --git a/.gitmodules b/.gitmodules
index 32170c2..f8cb154 100644
--- a/.gitmodules
+++ b/.gitmodules
@@ -1,3 +1,5 @@
 [submodule "scripts"]
        path = scripts
        url = ssh://git@github.com/chris3torek/scripts
+       branch = v1.0
+       tag = v1.0
```

The `branch =` is left over from my earlier `git submodule` command—let's remove it now, just to clean up:

```
$ git submodule set-branch --default scripts
$ git diff
diff --git a/.gitmodules b/.gitmodules
index 32170c2..71dcdd2 100644
--- a/.gitmodules
+++ b/.gitmodules
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
 [submodule "scripts"]
        path = scripts
        url = ssh://git@github.com/chris3torek/scripts
+       tag = v1.0
```

You can now retrieve this tag with `git config -f .gitmodules --get`:

```
$ git config -f .gitmodules --get submodule.scripts.tag
v1.0
```

The `git config` command is quite suitable for scripting; consult [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for more.  See also `git submodule foreach` in [the `git submodule` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) for a way to automatically run commands for each submodule.

(You don't have to store this tag information directly in `.gitmodules`, of course; any file will work, and that can insulate you from potential future Git changes.)

To turn a hash ID into a tag name, consider using `git tag --points-at` (assuming your Git version is at least 1.7.10):

```
git tag --points-at <hash>
```

will print the name(s) of the tag(s) that select that particular commit.  Note that you must run *this* Git command *in the submodule*, after using the superproject to find the hash ID.<sup>1</sup>

Last, to automate checking of submodules, consider the `git submodule status` and/or `git submodule summary` commands, which are also described in the `git submodule` documentation.

---

<sup>1</sup>One way to use the superproject to find the submodule's hash ID is to let Git run `git checkout` / `git switch` in the submodule, by running `git submodule update` in the superproject.  But if you just want to *read* the correct hash ID, use `git rev-parse`.  The submodule hash ID is stored in each commit as a *gitlink* entry, which is then copied to Git's index when checking out the superproject commit.  So you can, for instance, use:

```
git rev-parse <commit>:path/to/submodule
```

in the superproject to see the hash ID in the given commit, or:

```
git rev-parse :path/to/submodule
```

to see the hash ID currently stored in the superproject Git's index.